# Selenium MoveToElement() action scrolls to top when looped

Tags: c#, selenium

I am writing a loop that scrolls from post to post in a feed, to accomplish that I use the MoveToElement() action. I tried:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);


while (true)
{
    List<IWebElement> posts = new List<IWebElement>(driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("feed_row")));
    foreach (IWebElement k in posts)
    {
        action.MoveToElement(k);
        action.Perform();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    posts.Clear();
}
```

But when the loop is done looking at a post, it scrolls to the top of the page, after which it goes to the next post.
What could possibly cause this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. This isn't a quirk of Selenium, it's my error, when I clear every post from the list, the loop starts over again and fills the list with old posts and posts that have just loaded in, which is why Selenium moves to the top of the feed and starts over.